# how to get Dynamic checkbox control id's

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically generating checkboxes, all this wrote in page_load, when i try to check the checkbox it showing error,

**Error line:**

`CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chk" + j);`

Error:  Multiple controls with the same ID '1' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

My requirement is:

**if i check the checkboxes  i want count of the number of checkboxes checked and radio buttons will appeared relative checked checkboxes.**

Below is the code:

```
      string strfromdt = Session["leavefrm"].ToString();
        DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strfromdt);
        string strtodt = Session["leaveto"].ToString();
        DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strtodt);

        string strdays = Session["noofdays"].ToString();
        float daysf = float.Parse(strdays);
        float days = (float)Math.Ceiling(daysf);
        CheckBox chk;
        Label lbl;
        RadioButton rd;

        days++;

                OleDbCommand cmd;
                DbConnection.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("select HOL_DATE from IND_HOLIDAYS", DbConnection);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                for (int j = 1; j <= days - 1; j++)
                {
                    while(startDate <= endDate)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            string strdate = dt.Rows[i]["HOL_DATE"].ToString();
                            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(strdate);

                            if (startDate == date)

                                startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
                        }

                        if ((startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || ((startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)))
                        {
                            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }


                    chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.ID = j.ToString();
                    chk.AutoPostBack = true;
                    // chk.Checked = true;
                    lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    lbl.ID = j.ToString();
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(chk);

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton { });

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));

                    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);



                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chk" + j);

                   //chk.Checked = CheckBox1Checked;
                   //chk.oncheckedchanged += CheckBox1OnChecked;

                    int chkcount = 0;
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        chkcount++;
                    }
                    int chkcount1 = chkcount;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given the same ID to `chk` and `lbl` (both are `j.ToString()`), you need to make them unique:

```
chk.ID = string.Format("chk{0}", j);
lbl.ID = string.Format("lbl{0}", j);
// Now you can FindControl:
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chk" + j);
```

Comment: I am getting checkbox id, but even i checked the checkbox also id showing checked is false

Comment: I guess j is unique, it'll create upto days-1 number of checkboxes and labels with unique id because it's in a for loop.

Comment: @Anandaraj `j` would be unique if you only used it once. In this case it is used twice in the same loop

Comment: I am getting checkbox id, but even i checked the checkbox also id showing checked is false

Comment: @RGraham, Yes, I didn't see that both checkbox and label using same j.ToString() value. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Even i checked the checkbox also

Comment: CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chk" + j);               Even i checked the checkbox also the 'cb' showing checked = false

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dynamic controls in OnInit method in order for these to work correctly in all cases. I remember having issues with dynamic controls being added in Page_Load.

There is an error RGraham already pointed out with same IDs being added to different controls.

Also, there is this statement that doesn’t seem to have any purpose

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton { });